# Persistent issue with SQL Server and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I can resolve that issue anyhow.

> iOS Bundling failed 3954ms (C:\Users\Worstation\last\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js)
> The package at "node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "node: events".
> It failed because the native React runtime does not include the Node standard library.

I have installed `mssql` with `npm install mssql`, but nothing helps. Fighting with that problem already 2 days, I can't jump over it. The configuration is Nodejs latest, react-native latest, Expo CLI 50.0, Expo Go, don't know its version.

The `mssql` package is used here :

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();
```

Two days ago everything worked normally, I have no idea what happened. Please help.

I tried to do a clean install of everything(a couple of times), to update the versions, but nothing helped. My server is with IP, not localhost or name. And server.js file connects without any problems.

Comment: I guess an obvious question might be: have you used `npm install` to downgrade the `mssql` package reference to a previous working version? If that older version still works then you can explore what's wrong with the current version and submit a bug report against their project.